# Imported data not display

Tags: 2sxc

Imported data not displays in repeated table. It's only shows demo data. below is my template.

```
@{

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var Content in AsDynamic(Data["Default"]).OrderBy(m => m.wcName))
        {
            <tr>
            <td width="30%"><a href="@Content.link" target="_blank">@Content.wcName</a> </td>
                <td>@Html.Raw(@Content.wcPosition)
               @if (DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode())
                {
                   @Content.Toolbar
                }
             </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>    
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template only shows items assigned to this page/module, not "all data" - for that you would have to replace `Data["Default"]` with `App.Data["your-content-type-name"]`.

You probably want to read more about this here: http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/12-differences-when-templating-data-instead-of-content

Comment: Great, Thank you. :)