# Having Issues with 2sxc Data Import

Tags: 2sxc

Needing some help with Showing Imported data on my production site after exporting it from staging. After finishing up my updates on staging I installed 2sxc module on my production created my content types and my 2 views (Current award winners and past award winners). After that I imported my content type data which completed successfully and I can see all my imported data from admin. However, I have not been able to get my data to show for this my Current award winners view as it is on my staging. My view template is as follow:

```
    <div class="row">
    @{var Count = 1;}
    @foreach (var e in List) 
    {
        var Content = e.Content;
    <div class="col-sm-4 item-@Content.EntityId">
        <div class="img-thumb  item sc-element">
            @Content.Toolbar
            <a href="@Content.URL" title="@Content.Title">
                <img src="@Content.Image?w=200&h=200&mode=crop" class="img-responsive" title="@Content.EntityTitle">
            </a>
        </div>
        <p class="img-caption">
           <a href="@Content.URL" title="@Content.Title">@Content.Title</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    if ( Count %3 == 0 ) {
     <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
     }
     if ( Count %2 == 0 ) {
     <div class="clearfix hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
     }
     Count++;
    }
</div>
```

I have set everything up identical to how I have my stage set up. I did find a slack [Imported data not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956563/imported-data-not-display), and updated my code from `@foreach (var e in List)` to `@foreach (var Content in AsDynamic(App.Data["DCC Awards"]))`, which eventually did start showing my data. However, it showed all data for both of my views (current and past). This template should only show my current winners.

Answer (score 0):

So what your export/import seems to miss is the "which items were assigned to what dnn-module + their respective order". For this, you must export an app with the "Keep Content-Groups" check box activated. Best review the instructions on https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Copy-Duplicate-an-entire-Site